# Google Script: How do I get all messages from multiple threads into an array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My goal is to get all messages with a particular label into an array.

Currently I'm using [Gmailapp.search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)), which successfully gives me an array of Gmail threads with the label I've specified. Where I'm stuck is - extracting all the messages of the threads into an array. As you can see in the code below, I'm trying to use the [getMessagesForThreads()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getMessagesForThreads(GmailThread)) function, but with the code I have below, the number of threads and number of total messages is the same, which can't be right.

```js
function getRelevantMessages() 
{

var queried_Email_Threads = GmailApp.search ("label:expense tracking/Credit Card");
console.log('Number of threads queried:'+ queried_Email_Threads.length)

var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(queried_Email_Threads)
console.log('Total number of messages: ' + messages.length)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the official document of the method of `getMessagesForThreads`, the sample script is as follows.

```
// Log the subject lines of all messages in the first two threads of your inbox
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 2);
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(thread);
for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
    Logger.log("subject: " + messages[i][j].getSubject());
  }
}
```

When this sample script is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getRelevantMessages() {
  var queried_Email_Threads = GmailApp.search("label:expense tracking/Credit Card");
  console.log('Number of threads queried:' + queried_Email_Threads.length)

  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(queried_Email_Threads)
  console.log('Total number of messages: ' + messages.length)

  // I added below script.
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      res.push(messages[i][j]);
    }
  }
  console.log(res.length)
}
```

- From [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagesforthreadsthreads),

  > `GmailMessage[][]` (from `getMessagesForThreads`) - an array of arrays of messages, where each item in the outer array corresponds to a thread and the inner array contains the messages in that thread

#### References:

- [getMessagesForThreads(threads)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagesforthreadsthreads)

Comment: Perfect, this solved my problem! I thought the reason the documentation used the nested for loop, was to print on the console. But I guess its used to access emails in the thread. I'll research more to understand why the for loop is necessary.

Comment: @Jagrat Thank you for replying. At the official sample script, because `getMessagesForThreads` returns 2-dimensional array, the loop is used for retrieving both the thread and the messages. For example, when you want to retrieve only the total number of messages, I think that you can also use `flat()` like `var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(queried_Email_Threads).flat()`.